# Is this mysql query correct for getting data from two tables

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT r.`root_cat_name`,
       r.`root_cat_id`,
       s.`sub_cat_name`,
       s.`sub_cat_id`
  FROM `root_category` AS r
    INNER JOIN `sub_category` AS s ON r.`root_cat_id` = s.`sub_cat_id`
  ORDER BY r.`root_cat_id` DESC
```

I want to get data from 2 tables in which root_cat_id is the primary key.
I want to show all sub-categories.

root cat:

```
id  root_cat_name
--  -----
1   item1
2   item2
```

subcat:

```
id  root_cat_id sub_cat_name
--  ----------- ------
1   1           abc
2   1           sadj
3   2           asd
4   1           asdasd
```

Comment: it can't be correct with the tables as shown...there is no column 'root_cat_name'.

It does look like the join should be 'ON r.id = s.root_cat_id' though

Comment: btw I would recommend this site as a great way to debug and share your SQL problems :
http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: please check again.. i did few changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work :

```
SELECT r.root_cat_name,
    r.root_cat_id,
    s.sub_cat_name,
    s.sub_cat_id
FROM root_category AS r
INNER JOIN sub_category AS s ON r.id = s.root_cat_id
ORDER BY r.id DESC
```

everything in 'r' must be column names from root_category, everythin in 's' must be column names in sub_category

Answer (score 1):

```
INNER JOIN `sub_category` s ON r.`root_cat_id` = s.`sub_cat_id`
```

should be

```
 INNER JOIN `sub_category` s ON r.`id` = s.`root_cat_id`
```

=> you need to use the column names as they are defined in the tables

edit:
same principle applies for your `SELECT`.
If you want to have another column name displayed, use `AS`:

```
SELECT r.id AS root_id, ...
```